# Make a list from data ec2_instance/'s?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, cloudwatch-alarms

I have a list of servers stored as a list in locals as

```
locals {
  my_list = [
    "server1",
    "server2",
    "server3",
    "server4"
  ]
}
```

Can I fetch data for each server such as instace I'd etc using the locals above?  Without defining individual data blocks for each server.

Can I then put those attributes in a list? Finally how would I consume it later for the example below which is for just one server.  ( Below example is a cloud watch alarm dimension)

```
dimensions = {
  instanceid   = data.aws_instance.server1.instance_id
}
```

Comment: Please edit your Question to provide more information. For example, what do you mean by "fetch data for each server" -- what data are you seeking? What do you mean by "defining individual data blocks"? More information, please.

Comment: I have already mentioned that I need instance ids here. I have also mentioned I need to fetch information from servers using data. Its pretty straightforward for someone working on terraform what I am trying to do. I think you need to read my question again and refer to terraform 101 sorry. PS : I already have an answer from someone who understood my question quite clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide filter `instance-id` with your `my_list` (assuming `server1` is instance-id):

```
data "aws_instances" "my_instances" {

  filter {
    name   = "instance-id"
    values = local.my_list
  }

}
```

In case `my_list` contains **instance names**, then you can use:

```
data "aws_instance" "my_instances" {

  for_each = toset(local.my_list)  

  instance_tags = {
    Name = each.key
  }
}
```

and to get the `list` of instance ids:

```
values(data.aws_instance.my_instances)[*].id
```

Comment: Thank you , this works for instanced, but not for Name  

 `
dimensions = {
    instanceid   = values(data.aws_instances.my_instances)[*].ids
    instancename = values(data.aws_instances.my_instances)[*].Name
  }
`

` server2 = {
          + filter               = null
          + id                   = "us-west-2"
          + ids                  = [
              + "i-0b979e55437035e41",
            ]
          + instance_state_names = null
          + instance_tags        = {
              + "Name" = "server2"
            }
`

Comment: @user2499710 The name of your instances is you `local.my_list`.

Comment: using local.my_list gives me 

Inappropriate value for attribute "dimensions": element "instancename": string
required.

Comment: Also
    instanceid = values(data.aws_instances.my_instances)[*].ids


Gives me "
Inappropriate value for attribute "dimensions": element "instanceid": string
required.

Comment: @user2499710 I would suggest making new question. I don't know what `dimensions` is. What is it context? What exactly do you want to achieve? What are the errors. The answer I provided shows how to get detail information about instances as you asked. The dimension issue seems as a separate problem for me.

Comment: Apologies, posted as a new question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65556076/cloudwatch-alarm-for-list-of-servers)