# Cloudwatch alarm for list of servers

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, cloudwatch-alarms

I am trying to set a few alerts across a list of servers, I have my servers defined in locals as below:

```
  locals {
      my_list = [
        "server1",
        "server2"
      ]
    }
```

I then defined my cloudwatch alerts as so: (This is one such alert)

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "ec2-high-cpu-warning" {
  for_each            = toset(local.my_list)
  alarm_name          = "ec2-high-cpu-warning-for-${each.key}"
  comparison_operator = "GreaterThanThreshold"
  evaluation_periods  = "1"
  metric_name         = "CPUUtilization"
  namespace           = "AWS/EC2"
  dimensions = {
    instanceid   = values(data.aws_instances.my_instances)[*].ids
    instancename = local.my_list
  }

  period                    = "60"
  statistic                 = "Average"
  threshold                 = "11"
  alarm_description         = "This warning is for high cpu utilization for ${each.key}"
  actions_enabled           = true
  alarm_actions             = [data.aws_sns_topic.my_sns.arn]
  insufficient_data_actions = []
  treat_missing_data        = "notBreaching"
}
```

I also defined data source as so:

```
data "aws_instances" "my_instances" {

  for_each = toset(local.my_list)

  instance_tags = {
    Name = each.key
  }
}
```

Now when i run terraform plan i get an error:

```
| data.aws_instances.my_instances is object with 2 attributes
```

Inappropriate value for attribute "dimensions": element "instanceid": string
required.

Comment: You want to define one alarm per instance? So in your example, you will have two alarms created?

Comment: @marcin I want have multiple different alarms per instance, like cpu, memory etc, i only posted the cpu alarm here. Also yes, in my example above two alarm created one for each instance, correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `for_each` you should use `data.aws_instance.my_instances`:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "ec2-high-cpu-warning" {

  for_each            = data.aws_instance.my_instances
  
  alarm_name          = "ec2-high-cpu-warning-for-${each.key}"
  comparison_operator = "GreaterThanThreshold"
  evaluation_periods  = "1"
  metric_name         = "CPUUtilization"
  namespace           = "AWS/EC2"
  
  dimensions = {
    instanceid   = each.value.id
    instancename = each.key
  }

  period                    = "60"
  statistic                 = "Average"
  threshold                 = "11"
  alarm_description         = "This warning is for high cpu utilization for ${each.key}"
  actions_enabled           = true
  alarm_actions             = [data.aws_sns_topic.my_sns.arn]
  insufficient_data_actions = []
  treat_missing_data        = "notBreaching"
}
```

The above will create two alarms for your two instances (one alarm per instance) where `instancename` will be `server1` or ``server2`.